# Simple Makefile problem

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to compile a project that uses 2 .cc files and a .h

I'm writing a Makefile but it's not compiling, I get an error:

```
 make
g++ -I/usr/local/include/ -I/usr/local/include/libfreenect -I. -I/usr/include/GL -fPIC -g -Wall `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/lib -L/lib simple_gesture.cc -o simple_gesture  `pkg-config --libs opencv` -L/usr/local/lib -lfreenect -lglui -lglut -lGLU -lGL 
simple_gesture.cc: In function ‘void depth_cb(freenect_device*, void*, uint32_t)’:
simple_gesture.cc:315: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘clock_t’
simple_gesture.cc:315: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’
/tmp/cck2APvc.o: In function `depth_cb(_freenect_device*, void*, unsigned int)':
/home/dany/ToCompile/kinect-apps-playground-fingertip-detection/simple_gesture.cc:313: undefined reference to `FeatureExtractor::Process(unsigned char*, int const*, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [simple_gesture] Error 1
```

The Makefile is this:

```
all: simple_gesture

CFLAGS=-fPIC -g -Wall `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`
INCLUDE = -I/usr/local/include/ -I/usr/local/include/libfreenect -I. -I/usr/include/GL
FREE_LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -lfreenect
GL_LIBS = -lglui -lglut -lGLU -lGL 
GL_FLAGS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/lib -L/lib

feature_extractor: feature_extractor.h feature_extractor.cc
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(GL_FLAGS) $? -o $@  $(LIBS) $(FREE_LIBS) $(GL_LIBS)

simple_gesture:  simple_gesture.cc
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(GL_FLAGS) $? -o $@  $(LIBS) $(FREE_LIBS) $(GL_LIBS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o feature_extractor simple_gesture
```

I think I'm not linking well the files..

Any idea?

[edit]
solved

it was enough:

simple_gesture:  feature_extractor.h feature_extractor.cc simple_gesture.cc
$(CXX) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(GL_FLAGS) $? -o $@  $(LIBS) $(FREE_LIBS) $(GL_LIBS)

Comment: What's Process() function in feature_extractor? The error is linking error, so you might need to include another file.

Comment: Yes Process is feature_extractor. I don't think I need another include, I think the problem is just the Makefile because this code has been used also from other people

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your **simple_gesture.cc** depends on some function from *FeatureExtractor* class. So you should consider linking **feature_extractor.o** into your **simple_gesture**.

Comment: yes I was thinking a similar thing but I don't know how to do it in Makefiles, because if I do something like: all: simple_gesture feature_extractor                         I get other errors

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the binaries depend on the presence of the object files, not on the source files.  You already have a rule for turning the source into an object.

```
all: simple_gesture

LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`
INCLUDE = -I/usr/local/include/ -I/usr/local/include/libfreenect -I. -I/usr/include/GL
FREE_LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -lfreenect
GL_LIBS = -lglui -lglut -lGLU -lGL 
GL_FLAGS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/lib -L/lib
CFLAGS=-fPIC -g -Wall `pkg-config --cflags opencv` $(INCLUDE)

feature_extractor: feature_extractor.o
    $(CXX) $(GL_FLAGS) -o $@  $(LIBS) $(FREE_LIBS) $(GL_LIBS) $<

simple_gesture:  simple_gesture.o feature_extractor.o
    $(CXX) $(GL_FLAGS) -o $@  $(LIBS) $(FREE_LIBS) $(GL_LIBS) $<

%.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -rf *.o feature_extractor simple_gesture
```